# Accessing a label from a different form in qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I have a login page(main_window) and I want to set the username in the label created in `form_2`, after successful login. How can I access the username(line_edit) from `main_window` in `form_2`.
I have tried creating a function which is called from main_window class.
I am using Qt 5.9.

```
void login_card1::on_pushButton_clicked(){

QString us;
QSqlQuery q;
portal k;
q.prepare("select * from login where username = ? and password = ?");
q.addBindValue(ui->lineEdit->text());
q.addBindValue(ui->lineEdit_2->text());
if(q.exec())
{
    if(q.next())
    {
        us = ui->lineEdit->text();
        k.labeltext(us);
        ui->output->append("Welcome, opening portal...");
        portal p;
        p.setModal(this);
        p.exec();

    }
    else if(ui->lineEdit->text().isEmpty())
    {
        ui->output->append("please enter your username and password\nif you are a hacker please wait in the OFFICE ROOM...");
    }
    else
    {
        ui->output->append("incorrect username or password, please try again...");
    }



}}
```

code for textlabel function in form_2.cpp

```
void portal::labeltext(QString u){
    ui->label_2->setText(u);
}
```

Comment: @MichaelO. Where?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. After `portal p` add `p.labeltext(username)`